# Azure CloudService roles start order

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

Is there any way to configure in which order Azure should start CloudService roles ?
I need to start my ESB subscribers after my publishers.

Comment: How are you deploying your cloud services - Portal, PowerShell or some other way?

Comment: Visual Studio deployment for now

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could see is split that into two deployments and deploy one after the other for now manually and automate using PS later. Btw, have you tried resolving the dependency Pub Vs Sub through code rather than using deployment sequence?

Comment: I would definitely put effort into updating the subscribers so that they can handle / be aware of the publisher's state rather than trying to work around the platform.

Comment: Ya, this is what I'm totally aware of - just looking for some cheap, out of the box like solution :)